# facing problems with newly created function in codeigniter controller and model

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, codeigniter

(new to android dev) Hello. Mainly the reason why I added new function is for more restriction in retrieving in the database. Because I have two android apps, organizer and player, but uses same database as well as the php files.

First let me show you the function for **players** in **controller**

```
function laroforpi(){ //players listing of games
    if(!$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
        redirect('login');
    }
    $this->load->model('games_model');
    $data = $this->games_model->laroforpi();
    echo json_encode($data)
}
```

and for the **model**

```
function laroforpi(){
    if($this->input->post('brunning') == "true"){
        $this->db->where('user_id', $this->input->post('user_id'));
        $query = $this->db->get('game');//select * from game
        $data = $query->result_array();
        return $data;
    }
    else{
        $date = date('Y-m-d');
        $data = array(
        'status' = 'Publish',
        'startdate <=' => $date, 
        'enddate >= ' => $date
        );

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('game');
        $this->db->where($data);
        $result = $this->db->get(); 

        $row = $result->result();
        return $row;

    }
}
```

Also here is the code for **fetching**(?)

```
public static void getGameForPlayers(final Context context, final boolean brunning, final RequestCallback<JSONArray> callback){
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("user_id", user_id);
        params.put("brunning",/* brunning == true? "true" : "false" */ "false");
        new PostRequest("getgameforplayers", params, new RequestCallback<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(JSONArray response) {
                callback.onSuccess(response);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailed(String message) {
                callback.onFailed("Error encountered. " + (message != null ? message : "") + "Please try again!" );
            }
        }).execute();
}
```

every time I run it, the message "**error encountered**" returns so it is probably where the error is

Now the functions for the **organizer** (controller)

```
function getgame()//organizer list of games
{
    if(!$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
        redirect('login');
    }
    $this->load->model('games_model');
    $data = $this->games_model->getgame();
    echo json_encode( $data );
}
```

now for the **model**

```
function getgame()
{
    if($this->input->post('brunning') == "false"){
        $this->db->where('user_id', $this->input->post('user_id'));
        $query = $this->db->get('game');
        $data = $query->result_array();
        return $data;
    }
    else{
        $date = date('Y-m-d');
        $data = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM game where user_id = ".$this->input->post('user_id')." and ".
            "((startdate <= '".$date."' and '".$date."' <= enddate));");

        return $data->result_array();
    }

}
```

Normally I can run the organizers app but the two new functions should be in comments or else it wont fetch the needed data.
The same happens with the players app, when the two new functions is used it wont retrieve the data still. It has been days and I havent found any answer.

Comment: in your java object, what does this `getgameforplayers` refer to ? does this an url ?? and for the php side , if you tried to browse the data from your browser , do you got the same errors ? and check your apache log

Comment: the getgameforplayers refer to this $route['getgameforplayers'] = 'game/getgameforplayers' from route.php